# Поправьте формулу EXCEL

Tags: excel

Вот два скрина: http://prntscr.com/bin23c - это сама формула, прикреплю еще код сюда. Вот страница, где должна работать формула: http://prntscr.com/bin2ti

Если я подставляю данные в диапазон'Операции'!$A:$G , то таблица в любом случае = 0 В чем неправильность текущей формулы?

```
=iferror(QUERY('Операции'!$A:$G;"select SUM(E) where A >= date '2016-04-01' and A <= date '2016-04-31' and C = """&$A2&""" Label SUM(E) ''";);0)
```

Возможно есть аналоги данной формулы?

Comment: Ты скажи, что хочешь сделать вообще, а тебе уже подскажут какой формулой лучше это сделать)

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы считалось прибыль, расход, состояние на счетах и тд с одной страницы: Операции. Могу показать полную таблицу, для этого дай свой контакты:)

Comment: *batman* В этой секции пишутся ответы, уточняющие вопросы не являются ответом, они пишутся в комментариях.

Comment: @nick_n_a, знаю, но мне сказали, что недостаточно репутации для комментария(хз)

Comment: Мне нужно сделать чтобы считался доход, расход, остаток на счетах и прочее. Прикрепляю скрины полной таблицы:
Операции: http://prntscr.com/bozqee
Доход: http://prntscr.com/bozql2
Расход: http://prntscr.com/bozqsj

Comment: Кстати, не понятно почему расход считается, а доход нет.

Comment: @StokOne отправь на mstdpwnz@gmai.com, посмотрю

Comment: @batman отправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понимаю что означает `select SUM(E)`, но что мешает писать обычными формулами типа:

```
=если(МЕСЯЦ(СЕГОДНЯ())=7; [здесь указываем ячейку, если месяц = 7, ну или ссылку с этом самым label SUM(E)] ;0)
```

Этот вариант может сработать только для текущего года.